# How are modules loaded at boot

Tags: boot, modules

if I do "lsmod" I get a long list of loaded modules. Which file lists the modules to load at boot time?

I've seen pointers to /etc/modules but in my case it only contains "lp" and nothing more.

thanks
joe

Comment: Are you asking about the linux kernel internals and how modules are loaded ? Or are you asking about how to configure which modules are loaded? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules